# Compute new inverse when old inverse and new and old matrix known

Tags: matrices, inverse

Say I have a matrix $M$ and know its inverse $M^{-1}$. Then every element changes so that $M'=M+(M'-M)$. Is there a fast way to find $M'^{-1}$ from this information? That is without computing the new inverse from scratch (naively a $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ calculation)?

Comment: Note that your question is equivalent to the following: Let $M$ and $M'$ be matrices and let $M^{-1}$ be known. Compute $M'^{-1}$. As long as you do not have any information as how $M$ and $M'$ are related, this is hopeless (the equation you gave holds for all matrices $M$,$M'$).

Comment: Good point.. So no go.

Comment: In general, but there are results that apply if $M$ and $M'$ are related in a particular way, for example, if their difference $M' - M$ has rank $1$.

Comment: @Travis In my case $M'$ and $M$ have equal rank. Do you know of any other cases with useful results?

Comment: @jorgen If their difference is nilpotent there might well be a closed formula. What do you know about $M, M'$?

Comment: Let's see I have a pretty complicated expression for each element in terms of a particle configuration (coordinates for all particles). Every element depends on every coordinate. To be honest I'm not sure about all the properties of the matrices or their difference (the matrix' determinant is a quantum mechanical wavefunction) but I _do_ know that the difference is neither rank 1 nor nilpotent.

Comment: Are the matrices $M$ and $M'$ at least supposed to be somewhat close to each other?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Hm yes I suppose they are (somewhat); since they are continuous functions of the configuration and the change in configurations is not big. However this could be slightly difficult to control. What do you have in mind?